# How to run Node.js webdriverio Appium tests on AWS Device Farm

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I got a working configuration locally. Running test with Node webdriverio
But I want to automate this with de device farm

```js
const webdriverIO = require("webdriverio");

const opts = {
    path: '/wd/hub',
    port: 4723,
    capabilities: {
        platformName: "Android",
        platformVersion: "9",
        deviceName: "emulator-5554",
        app: __dirname +"/app-debug.apk",
        appPackage: "com.ayga.cooktop",
        appActivity: ".MainActivity",
        automationName: "UiAutomator2"
    }
};


const main = async () => {
    const client = await webdriverIO.remote(opts);
    .... actual tests
};

void main();
```

My build file:

```yaml
version: 0.1

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - nvm install 12.16.1
      - echo "Navigate to test package directory"
      - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
      - npm install *.tgz
      - export APPIUM_VERSION=1.14.2
      - avm $APPIUM_VERSION
      - ln -s /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/.bin/appium  /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js
  pre_test:
    commands:
      - echo "Start appium server"
      - >-
        appium --log-timestamp
        --default-capabilities "{\"deviceName\": \"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME\", \"platformName\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\",
        \"app\":\"$DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH\", \"udid\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID\", \"platformVersion\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\",
        \"chromedriverExecutable\":\"$DEVICEFARM_CHROMEDRIVER_EXECUTABLE\"}"
        >> $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt 2>&1 &

      - >-
        start_appium_timeout=0;
        while [ true ];
        do
            if [ $start_appium_timeout -gt 60 ];
            then
                echo "appium server never started in 60 seconds. Exiting";
                exit 1;
            fi;
            grep -i "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723" $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt >> /dev/null 2>&1;
            if [ $? -eq 0 ];
            then
                echo "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723";
                break;
            else
                echo "Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second";
                sleep 1;
                start_appium_timeout=$((start_appium_timeout+1));
            fi;
        done;

  test:
    commands:
      - echo "Navigate to test source code"
      - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/node_modules/*
      - echo "Start Appium Node test"
      - node index.js
  post_test:
    commands:
artifacts:
  - $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR
```

my test runs, but i was not able to find the apk

[image]

How to I tell AWS the apk, deviceName and etc

```js
const opts = {
    path: '/wd/hub',
    port: 4723,
    capabilities: {
        platformName: "Android",
        platformVersion: "9",
        deviceName: "emulator-5554",
        app: __dirname +"/app-debug.apk",
        appPackage: "com.ayga.cooktop",
        appActivity: ".MainActivity",
        automationName: "UiAutomator2"
    }
};
```

Comment: This is just a warning message and may or may not affect your run based on how you packaged the file. In many cases, its fine. You can follow the **Configure Your Appium Test Package** section for **Node** on the [AWS Device Farm Appium docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-appium.html) for help with packaging your file.

Comment: @TobeE editted the question.I needed to npm-bundle my whole repo in orde to run the tests properly. I got stuck somewhere else now., please help

Comment: You don't need to set the `app`, `platformVersion`, nor `deviceName` capabilities on AWS Device Farm. The service adds these capabilities it for you. There's probably some mis-configuration going on there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the capabilities to the AWS provided ENVVARS just like below.

```js
const apkInfo = {
    appPackage: "com.ayga.cooktopbt",
    appActivity: "com.ayga.cooktop.MainActivity",
    automationName: "UiAutomator2"
};

const awsOptions = {
    path: '/wd/hub',
    port: 4723,
    capabilities: {
        ...apkInfo,
        platformName: process.env.DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME,
        deviceName: process.env.DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME,
        app: process.env.DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH,
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank for reply. Did you change something in device farm's .yml file? Default .yml file doesnt update .env file. Is it work for you?

Comment: I found a documentation from aws. It says 'yes, you can use env file'.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environment-env.html